# RDP over WAN with IPV6 not working

Tags: networking, router, remote-desktop, ipv6

About a month ago I moved to fiber connection at my home, with that my ISP was changed as well.
I have found out that the new ISP is using CGNAT and therefor I'm unable to RDP to my IPV4 as before.
Since they want extra payment for a permeant IPV4 public IP, I have decided to try working with IPV6 instead.

Inside my home environment I'm able to RDP both my PCs with IPV6, from each PC to the other, but not from outside, when I'm trying to access from EC2 machine in AWS with IPV6.

I think that the issue in my case if the firewall in my home-grade router which was provided by the ISP.
Despite I can access the router settings I was unable to open the RDP port (TCP 3389) over IPv6.

Tried to call the ISP support but as soon as they heard IPV6 it was like I came from another planet for them,
Attached a screenshot from my home router, what I’m trying to achieve is to open access from “any” IPV6 address.

How can I achieve this?
Many thanks

[you can see screenshot of my router firewall in this link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2elCi.jpg)

Comment: Have you tested various other ports, e.g. 3390 for a start? (Much like residential ISPs often filter packets to MS-SMB ports to limit the spread of worms/botnets, I would not be surprised if your ISP also filtered the RDP port for the same reason.)

Comment: my friend, you are simply a genius, that was the issue!  I couldnt even think that they would be blocking ports, thank you!